# "Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error" when installing Aptana Studio

Tags: html, php

When I try to install Aptana Studio I get the message:

> Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error

What is this error and how it can be removed?

[image]

Comment: what means..? i just started learning web development by watching videos and according to video i downloaded aptana but when installing this error shows but i video there is no such error,so i couldnt figure out  what is the problem

Comment: I meant have you tried Googling first :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem with the Aptana installer. Download and install http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows from the Aptana site and then rerun the Aptana normal installer and that should resolve the issue for you.

Comment: The website doesn't exist! I still have this issue, my installer version is 3.6.1

Comment: The go server with the download link appears to have gone offline for some unknown reason @SidS so what you can do is going into your command prompt and opening it to the folder your Aptana installer is in run the command `Aptana_Studii_3_Setup_3.6.1.exe /extract:"folder"`. Now this command assumes you are running cmd as administrator, and the installer file name is Aptana_Studii_3_Setup_3.6.1.exe.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Rutherfurd. What is the file path of the installation, i am going on use this command to extract it to the file path.

Comment: It is wherever you put the installer. Make it easy and move the installer file to C: drive then simply run the file path as C: